# regular expression not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

error- Reported Link should be in Proper format. i have one text box im nvalidating proper link/url or not.below is valid link but its showing invalid. can u tell me wat to add in regex?

http://s1370.photobucket.com/user/homeocareint/media/Thyroid%201_zpspsho5jgu.jpeg.html?filters[user]=140973880&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Vldt_Re_RportLink" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- :|./?_%&=]*)?"
                                ControlToValidate="TxtBox_RportdLink" ErrorMessage="<img src='Images/Wrong.png' height='16' width='16'/>Reported Link should be in Proper format"
                                runat="server">
```

Comment: what are you trying / what are the requirements / what is the expected result / what is the error you're getting?

Comment: that is just one link or url . i have to validate that link any how . because thats showing website in that link

Comment: ^ and you need to escape the `/` delimiters like `\/`

Comment: can u show me full validation expression regex???

Comment: I'm not talking about the "correctness" of your regex, but to fix the error, you can use `http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w- :|.\/?_%&=]*)?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the both `[]` are not in the list of the valid characters so the url is valid until

`[user]=140973880&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0`

solution:

`http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w-\[\] :|./?_%&=]*)?` (added `\[\]`)